Is there any way to know which file is searched for property placeholder
I am having this error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'datasource.driver' in value "${datasource.driver}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:178)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer$PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver.resolveStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveStringValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitPropertyValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:225)

When executing my java application:  'datasource.driver' placeholder is nowhere to be found.
Unfortunately I am working on a very old undocumented project with a lot of config files.
How do I know which file is searched for placeholders ?

Check which profile your project is running on, such as dev, prod, or test, to find the correct configuration file.
For more information, please change the log level of the application and edit your question with more details.
logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG


It appears that the log level is already on debug mode. Spring only provides the application-context file used for loading.
In this file there is a long list of property files (more than 30) I will have to search all those file where previous coders named their properties with the same name...
